# Playframework: Best Solution for loading & using constant Strings

Tags: playframework, application-singleton

I have a bunch of static Strings that I'd like to store in a .yml file. What's the best design practice to load them to a Java Class & use it.

In other words, I'm looking for an Application-wide Singleton class holding resource strings, but confused as to where to put them (Models, Controllers).

I also don't want to make any obvious mistakes that'll hit performance

Update: found the solution
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/i18n#messages

Comment: if you found the solution please answer your own question and accept your answer, as per SO guidelines :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: found the solution http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/i18n#messages

Answer (score 3):

Although you found the solution, just a little note - by convention, most of your code lives in the "controllers", "models", and "views" packages (and the "notifiers" package if you use stuff like templated mail), but nothing bars you of adding more of your own. I often end up with at least a "utils" package :)